# Ubuntu 20.04 headphones detected but no sound

Tags: dual-boot, sound, 20.04, headphones, headset

So, after my computer started to be a bit slow this week, I decided to do a reboot. After, the sound output of my headset was not working at all and it seems to me that I have not changed anything on my computer before this infamous reboot. I've had many problem in the past with my output sound on my headset with things like headset not detected, and for this, I always used the command :

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

And, after a couple of tries, my headset would work again. But this time, it is a bit different, the command does not work and the headset IS detected (The headset works perfectly fine on windows). The speakers of my computers works fine and the sound has no problems to go through my HDMI port.

In **Settings - Sound**, it even says that sound is going to my headset (the little sound bar is moving just normally with my music), same thing with `pavucontrol`. Also, `alsamixer` seems quite normal to me (it seems to be the right sound card since I only got one), nothing out of ordinary. Last thing, I got a microphone integrated in my headset from which I can be heard without problems.

Some information about my laptop ASUS GL703V:
-I use dual-boot with Windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04.
-The output of `$ lspci | grep Audio` is : `00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)`
-My sound card according to Alsamixer : HDA Intel PCH
-My chip according to Alsamixer : Realtek ALC295

What have I tried to correct the problem? First, I got to say I don't really understand most of the commands I've tried.

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload 

sudo alsactl restore

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base

sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-\`uname -r\` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-\`uname -r\` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status || ubuntu-security-status; sudo usermod -aG \`cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'\` \`whoami\`
```

I also tried to change the file `analog-output-headphones.conf` in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/`. I changed

```
[Element Speaker]
switch = off
volume = off
```

to

```
[Element Speaker]
switch = on
volume = ignore
```

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you, except for a ASUS GL503 (but also Realtek ALC295). It drove me nuts as I tried every conceivable sound fix that I have seen for Ubuntu and derived systems. In the end, it appears it is kernel related and it mostly affects us ASUS users. There is a discussion here:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sound-from-speakers-no-sound-from-3-5mm-jack-audio/5343/20

The easiest solution for me was to edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (I think on some computers, it may be just alsa.conf) and insert this as the last line:
options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode

Then do a complete shutdown and restart.

It is possible that this change may cause you to lose the microphone in the headset, if you have one. In that case, you will probably have to try one of the other options in the link that I posted above, which will probably require you to recompile your Kernel with the applicable patch.

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much, it worked and even my microphone still works!

Comment: That is fantastic news! Glad I could help. Since I went through the same issue I completely understand your frustration.

Comment: @BenB Many thanks!!! I have been looking around for solutions and this worked like a charm. This problem have been driving me crazy for a month.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me also (Ubuntu 20.04 with Asus UX530U)

Comment: This also worked for me BUT not after a reboot. It did work after a shutdown and then a switch on. Difficult to believe but truth, or there is a logical explanation?

Comment: You save my day!

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too. And my sound settings didn't even show the headphones as being detected before doing this.

Comment: Worked here too! Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Latitude 3540. Thanks!

Comment: It's important that we HAVE TO DO **SHUTDOWN** instead of __*Reboot*__

Comment: Yep, it works ! Thank you so much <3!

Comment: I confirm that this solution also works on ASUS ROG GL703VD-GC028T with Linux Mint 20.3

Comment: I've "Creative SoundBlaster Z" It used to be work but from few weeks it didn't plays sound (OK on Windows). Sometimes very distorted sound comes out some sometimes completely silent. It shows that sound is playing but not hearing anything.

Answer (score 9):

There is a workaround for the problem you are facing, I am having the same issue with Realtek ACL295 (Asus Rog GL503). So here is what I found as a fix.

If you want to use Headphone but are willing to sacrifice the headphone mic

Go to :

> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Add the following line at the end as suggested by Ben B

```
options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode
```

Restart Your System.

If you want to use External Microphone but are willing to sacrifice the headphone (hearing) , then replace the above line with the following:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=headset-multi
```

Restart Your System.

NOTE: IN BOTH THE CASES YOUR SPEAKERS STILL WORK FINE. HOWEVER, IN THE LATTER, YOUR BUILT-IN MIC WORKS. I PREFER THE SECOND OPTION.

The first option is good, if you want to use headphone mics, external mics etc.

*[UPDATE]*: **This morning I was completely able to fix this issue where you can now use all your headsets with microphones by replacing all the above lines with the following:**

```
options snd_hda_intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

**Even if your system is not a dell system, it'll still work since the setting is for Realtek ALC295 and not a particular brand in general.**

Once you do this, restart your system, and try plugging in a headphone

Now it will give you an option to choose what type of device it is.

THIS IMAGE HERE

[image]

P.S -> They are visible in notification panel due to Gnome Extensions. You can go in settings and choose your preference.

Comment: This worked perfectly with my Intel NUC10 (BXNUC10i7FNH4) running Ubuntu 20.04. Before this the only way I could use the headphone jack was to use pavucontrol and change the Configuration > Profile to the 'Analog Stereo Duplex'. However that was listed as 'Unavailable' so the change would not persist. Now the change persists and works across reboot and login ... etc.

Comment: Thank you, the `dell-headset-multi` worked for me on an Asus Maximus Z790.

Answer (score 2):

I had some success with uninstalling timidity:

```
sudo apt-get remove timidity
```

I do still have to run the pulseaudio/alsa reload, but at least it works now.

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I've randomly had the same or similar issue and the solution is possibly too simple to widely apply. I have the PulseAudio Volume Control app installed. When I experience the no sound from headphones problem I run it (pavucontrol-qt in my case, but from the menu). Then I go to the Output Devices tab and from the drop-down I select Headphones (sometimes it's tagged Unplugged and sometimes it's tagged  Plugged in, doesn't matter, just select it) and then the headphones work. So no command line exercises.

I have not been able to identify any pattern to debug why the loss of audio happens and I have no idea why the manual intervention with PAV works. It just does work for me.

KInfoCenter shows both NVidia Corporation GP104 High Defintion Audio Controller and Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio, but I don't know which is active or how to determine that. Maybe the presence of both on the PCI bus is somehow confusing things.

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-45-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 12 × Intel® Core™ i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
Memory: 31.3 GiB of RAM

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, unfortunately, it does not work for me. I installed pavucontrol-qt as you use, but when I plug my headphones, it says it is indeed plugged in, and it even says there is sound on the volume-meter, but there is absolutely no sound coming out of any headset I plug. The problem is also not the output jack, cause on windows, I have no sound issues.

Comment: When you went into PAV control, did you try toggling, so altho it shows the headphones pluggedin, switching to Line Out (unplugged), exiting, returning and selecting the Headphones again. This toggling has been needed in some cases on my system.

Comment: I just tried, and it does not correct my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this for almost a month, and tried multiple online fixes but the simplest solution I happened to try was removing pulse audio and increasing bass speaker settings in alsamixer. And ta-da! Headphones started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw executing `alsactl kill quit && alsactl init` helped in my instance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing and re-installing alsa and pulseaudio and it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio && sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload
```