# No Sound Dell XPS 17 (9700) Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, 21.10

I had a problem with headphone mic not working and as I was trying different solutions a sound completely stopped working. First there was a "Dummy Output" and

```
$pacmd list-cards 
0 card(s) available.
```

I tried to reinstall

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep snd
[    3.768637] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    3.768711] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.769004] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    3.769009] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
```

and now situation is like

```
$ sudo pacmd list-sinks
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

I tried many thinks and as I understand it would be better if I'd install 20.04 with better sof version.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

and many other thinks. Is there any way to reinstall sound drivers to get sound back (with headphones and headphone mic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling to 20.04 everything started to work... until it stopped again (no particular reason ). Headphones and both microphones (headphone mic and internal microphone) stopped working. The funny thing was that everything seemed ok, but no sonud came out.

I found again all related posts but this time I was more ceareful about trying solutions. This post helped me:

[Ubuntu 20.04 headphones detected but no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272908/ubuntu-20-04-headphones-detected-but-no-sound)

By adding  opening this file:

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and adding this line to the end of the file

```
options snd-hda-intel model=headset-multi
```

and restarting the system. This solution did not work before since I probably tried too many solutions.

Posts suggests also this version:

```
options snd_hda_intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

If anyone would be interested in details, this is output

[http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=242600c91e53e943819e10df1b855b025d6b7441](https://alsa-project.org/db/?f=242600c91e53e943819e10df1b855b025d6b7441)

of command:

```
wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh
```