# Another Dell XPS no audio ("Dummy Audio") - Clean install of 23.04

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, xps, 23.04

I have a new Dell XPS 17 9730 and did a clean install of Ubuntu 23.04.

```shell
$ sudo lshw
xps-17-9730              
    description: Notebook
    product: XPS 17 9730 (0BDA)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
```

```shell
$ sudo lshw -C sound
  *-usb:1                   
       description: Video
       product: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate
       vendor: CKFME19T05344001DB70
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@3:6
       logical name: input11
       logical name: /dev/input/event7
       logical name: input12
       logical name: /dev/input/event8
       version: 24.41
       serial: SN0001
       capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D2p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=64
       resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:620-61f irq:224 memory:628f2e0000-628f2e3fff memory:628f000000-628f0fffff
```

Notice the kernel driver in use below (`sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl`):

```shell
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0bda
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 224, IOMMU group 19
    Memory at 628f2e0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 628f000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 19
    Memory at 628f2ec000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
```

```shell
$ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-sdw-acpi.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko model=generic
```

```shell
$ sudo more /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blackli
st snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --us
e-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2

# Added by John Manko 2023.08.13
# Fix now audio on Dell XPS
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384538/no-sound-dell-xps-17-9700-ubuntu-21-10
#options snd-hda-intel model=headset-multi
#options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

```shell
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep pipewire
gstreamer1.0-pipewire:amd64         install
libpipewire-0.3-0:amd64             install
libpipewire-0.3-common              install
libpipewire-0.3-modules:amd64           install
pipewire:amd64                  install
pipewire-alsa:amd64             install
pipewire-audio                  install
pipewire-bin                    install
pipewire-libcamera:amd64            install
pipewire-pulse                  install
```

```shell
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep alsa
alsa-base                   install
alsa-topology-conf              install
alsa-ucm-conf                   install
alsa-utils                  install
gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64             install
pipewire-alsa:amd64             install
```

```shell
$ sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'timidity-daemon' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```shell
$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/sound -name snd-hda-intel.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
```

```shell
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep linux
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu           install
console-setup-linux             install
libselinux1:amd64               install
linux-base                  install
linux-firmware                  install
linux-generic-hwe-22.04             install
linux-headers-6.2.0-20              install
linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic          install
linux-headers-6.2.0-27              install
linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic          install
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04         install
linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic            install
linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic            install
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04           install
linux-libc-dev:amd64                install
linux-modules-6.2.0-20-generic          install
linux-modules-6.2.0-27-generic          install
linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-20-generic        install
linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-27-generic        install
linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-27-generic   install
linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04  install
linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-27-generic   install
linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-27-generic    install
linux-sound-base                install
pptp-linux                  install
util-linux                  install
util-linux-extra                install
```

```shell
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep plumber
libwireplumber-0.4-0:amd64          install
wireplumber                 install
```

```shell
$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 2: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```shell
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      DellInc.-XPS179730--0358MX
```

```shell
$ sudo dmesg | grep -e 'audio\|snd\|intel'
[   64.067987] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[   64.069994] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
[   64.074430] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
[   64.494478] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   64.610425] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   66.339416] intel-hid INTC1078:00: platform supports 5 button array
[   66.380235] intel_rapl_msr: PL4 support detected.
[   66.380419] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[   66.380439] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[   66.380440] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   66.380441] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
[   66.417916] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[   66.421314] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0040-0041.sfi
[   67.024444] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[   67.028333] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[   67.088181] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[   67.088239] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[   67.088252] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   67.088469] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[   67.155152] intel_tcc_cooling: TCC Offset locked
[   68.047189] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-0040-0041.ddc
[   68.335533] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   68.394397] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[   68.409091] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: No SoundWire machine driver found
[   68.409095] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
[   68.409097] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[   68.409100] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 0
[   68.410587] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[   68.410591] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[   68.410597] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[   68.523247] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[   68.523254] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[   68.529789] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[  217.037508] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[  217.037528] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[  217.037738] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[  217.037806] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[  217.044733] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[  217.056326] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: No SoundWire machine driver found
[  217.056328] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
[  217.056329] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[  217.056331] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 0
[  217.056432] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[  217.056433] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[  217.056437] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[  217.171450] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[  217.171465] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[  217.172058] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
```

Everything seems in order.  I just can't get the device recognized!  So frustrating.

UPDATE:

Following the suggestions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479661/new-22-04-install-cannot-play-sound-on-speakers) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci), I installed the firmware from [thesofproject/sof-bin](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin).

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/intel/sof* some_backup_location/
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sof-*     some_backup_location/ # optional
sudo ./install.sh v2.2.x/v2.2
```

With an updated `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1
```

Still no change.

Comment: I've got the same issue on a 9730. A live boot with kernel 5.19.0-32-generic (e.g. Ubuntu 22.10) works, but doesn't work with newer versions. Haven't had the time to pin-point the exact issue yet though. So if you find it out - please share!

Comment: @vsimkus Will do.