# Headset not working after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04?

Tags: sound, headphones

My headset used to work at Ubuntu 18.04 (using USB Pnp Audio Device).

After upgrade, its still is displayed, but there is no sound:
[image]

There is either no sound at all, or the sound comes from my laptop. Headphones are plugged in.

I run `sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/snd/*` and rebooted as explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/1249071, but no success.

I also added the `snd-hda-intel-model=..` option to alsa-base.conf as explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/1273303 but it was also not working.

This is my audio device that plays no sound:

[image]

I of course checked that my headphones are turned on and are still working on another machine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by following these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Step 1 #1A made it all work by running

```
killall pulseaudio; pulseaudio -k  ; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

waiting 10s and then

```
pulseaudio --start
```