# Headphones detected but not playing sound after installing 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and when I plug my headphones into the front panel audio jack they are detected but no sound is played.

The headphones work fine with the audio jack using windows, and I can get sound in Ubuntu 22.04 using a Bluetooth speaker.

I followed this answer [Ubuntu 20.04 headphones detected but no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272908/ubuntu-20-04-headphones-detected-but-no-sound) and edited the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file as suggested but it hasn't worked.

I installed 'Pulse Audio Volume Control'.  When playing a video in Firefox with the headphones plugged in, pulse audio says the output is 'USB Audio Analog stereo' and there is no option to specifically select headphones.  Under settings > sound, it states 'Headphones - USB audio' but it does not indicate any sound is being played, neither does any sound play when i click test.  Any suggestions on how to fix are much appreciated.

Images of pulse audio and settings:

[image]

[image]